# Can I update libc.so.6 with no risk of breaking the server?

Tags: opensuse, glibc

I have a server which for different reasons I cannot upgrade. It's running SUSE 11.4. I need to run a package that requires GLIBC_2.14, and I have GLIB_2.11

The error I'm getting is:

```
/software/AMBER12/amber12/bin/xaLeap: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /software/AMBER12/amber12/bin/xaLeap)
```

I cannot install the library using the package manager because the system is so old that this is not supported anymore. At least is not fetching the updates anymore. So, the question is, if I manage to install the missing library, will I break my system? Since it is an update of libc.so.6, do you know if it will also require the update of other dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glibc is one of the core libraries on a Linux system.  It is a.ordinary reason why upgrading from CentOS  5 to 6 isnt recommended without a reinstall.

In short mucking with those libraries has a high chance of rendering your system unbootable.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just wanted to double check. Thanks.